# How to create a binary to decimal program?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Need to make a binary to decimal program and this is the furthest I have come:

The binary 101110 is supposed to represent 46 in decimal. But this prints out 11. Any help is appreciated.

***My code:***

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_to_number(int binary_digits[], int number_of_digits)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int n = -1;
    int i = 0;

    for ( i = number_of_digits - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            n++;

            if (binary_digits[i] == 1)
                sum = sum + (2^n);
    }
    return sum;
}

#ifndef WEBSUBMIT
int main()
{
     int binary_digits[6] = {1,0,1,1,1,0};
     cout << "" << binary_to_number(binary_digits, 6) << endl;
}
#endif //WEBSUBMIT
```

Comment: The `^` operator is *not* an exponent operator, it's XOR. Try to think of a way to do it with the left-shift operator `<<` instead.

Comment: C++ is not a scripting language, so the strict answer is that you can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is reworked code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int binary_to_number(int binary_digits[], int number_of_digits)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int cnt = number_of_digits;


    for (i = 0; i < number_of_digits; i++) {
        cnt--;

        if (binary_digits[i] == 1)
            sum = sum + pow(2, cnt);

    }
    return sum;
}

#ifndef WEBSUBMIT
int main()
{
    int binary_digits[6] = { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 }; //46
    cout << "" << binary_to_number(binary_digits, 6) << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
#endif //WEBSUBMIT
```

binary_digits[0] is 1 no 0
binary_digits[0] is 2 ^ 5

```
int binary_digits[6] = { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0 };
```

Comment: `<iostream>` includes `<math>` or `<cmath>` so `pow()` is declared?  Curious...  Granted that's a direct transliteration/fix to the OPs program, but I'm not convinced that it is a good way of writing the code.

Comment: pow is included throught iostream, because iostream including, istream and istream including math ..